# IKImageBrowserView Alternative

Tags: macos, cocoa

IKImageBrowserView is great, but it turns on discrete graphics, which is too much for the purpose I'm using it for.

Can anyone recommend an alternative (third-party or included) view which can be used to show a fixed number of small (16x16) images, where a user can select one of the images?

For clarification, this is what I'm using IKImageBrowserView for in my app:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSCollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

It supports selection and bindings.